# SharePoint button to link to Shared Network Drive

Tags: html, links, network-drive

I have been trying to use the following, to createa button on my SharePoint site that will open a folder on my Shared Network Drive.

I can hyperlink the network drive manually and it works. However, when I use the button it does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today's browsers don't support the `file://` protocol, so that would be a blocker.